# How do I constrain a table by the relation of another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    category_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_category FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE programs (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    image TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE program_tag (
    program_id INT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (program_id, tag_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_program FOREIGN KEY(program_id) REFERENCES programs(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tag FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id)
);
```

I want each program to contain only one tag from each category. Programs can take one tag from different categories. I couldn’t find how to do this.

Note: I'm looking for a way to solve this with just schema without trigger

Comment: You can't do this without using a trigger.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver So is using trigger a good approach? Can't we do this by changing the schema?

Comment: Your current data model doesn't support this requirement: You can't create a unique constraint for this. A trigger could do some checks, but only for records that have been committed. Any concurrent transaction can bypass the checks you could do in the trigger. And you would have the same issue using any other technology for this check. Changing your datamodel is the only option for a constraint. Or accept the fact that there is a small chance that somebody can bypass this requirement.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, not strictly true it is possible to use from here [Transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/transaction-iso.html) *13.2.3. Serializable Isolation Level*. Though that adds another layer of complexity and I would agree the changing the model is a better idea.

Comment: Not “pretty” but this might work 1) on the tags table make id + category_id a unique constraint 2) on program_tag add category_id and make program_id + category_id the FK to tags 3) on program_tag make program_id + carptegory_id a unique constraint

Comment: @NickW, what is `program_id + category_id` going to reference in `tags`? Are you thinking maybe `tag_id + category_id`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant tag_id not program_id

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Serializable Isolation Level also destroys concurrency. Maybe there is no need for concurrency, that's something not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Category CA exists.
--
category {CA}
      PK {CA}
```

- Each tag is in *exactly one* category.
- For each category, *more than one* tag *may be* in that category.

```
-- Tag TG is in category CA.
--
tag {TG, CA}
 PK {TG}
 SK {TG, CA}

FK {CA} REFERENCES category {CA}
```

```
-- Program PR exists.
--
program {PR}
     PK {PR}
```

- For each program and tag-category, that program can have *at most one* tag from that category.

```
-- Program PR is tagged with tag TG of category CA.
--
program_tag {PR, TG, CA}
         PK {PR, CA} 

FK1 {PR}     REFERENCES program {PR}
FK2 {TG, CA} REFERENCES tag     {TG, CA}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm confused about this: What happens if I enter the wrong category_id on the client side in the program_tag {PR, TG, CA} table?

Comment: Your request was *I want each program to contain only one tag from each category*,  as long as that is the case then your request is met. If you want the database to parse intent then that is a whole another problem.

Comment: @PehrSibusiso, The `FK2 {TG, CA}` prevents that as long as all tags are properly defined in `tag {TG, CA}`

Comment: @DamirSudarevic Thanks for your answer. I couldn't find how to do SK {TG, CA} in tags table as SQL. Any chance to add an example?

Comment: @PehrSibusiso `ALTER TABLE tag ADD CONSTRAINT unq_tag UNIQUE (TG,CA);`